# Laravel 5.5 Multi Authentication Routing wrong login form showing

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I am Trying to get Laravel multiple authentication to work on one of my projects. I've tried multiple things but I keep getting stuck. I currently have two guards defined, two models, two login controllers, etc.

If I go to /login - works as expected

If I go to /home (without being logged in) - I get redirected to the login page  as expected

If I go to /register- works as expected

If I go to /admin/login - I am presented with the default login form instead of the admin login form

If I go to /admin/admin/login - I am presented with the correct admin login form

My routes file:

```
    Auth::routes();
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    Route::prefix('admin')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
    Route::post('/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@login')->name('admin.login.submit');
   Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
});
```

And this is my Auth file:

```
    return [

    // Authentication Defaults

    'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
    // Authentication Guards

    'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
    'admin-api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
],
// User Providers

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],

],
      // Resetting Passwords

'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'provider' => 'admins',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 30,
        ],
    ],
];
```

Here is my adminLoginController file:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AdminLoginController extends Controller
{
public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('guest:admin');
}
public function showLoginForm() {
    return view('auth.admin-login');
}
public function login(){
    //validate the form data

    // atttempt to log in the user

    // if successful redirect to their admin dashboard 

     // if unsuccessful then redirect back to the login
    }
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something. It may be simple but it is delaying my progress. Every other thing works. It's just getting the /admin route to use the right middleware...I think...maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem before and later got a solution for it.
Actually the mistake I had commited which I think you may have done too was to have a folder named Admin and in it there was no login file in it so typing /admin/login made laravel to look for the file in there, miss it and then go to the default login file. What solved my problem was renaming the folder and everything worked. Try that if you have done the same mistake

Comment: Actually that was my mistake too. I have changed and just like magic it is working